# Recursion in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive program where the next function call is based on data from the previous iteration.

To give you an idea what I am trying to do:

you start at point a and you are interested where you can go to from this point, so the algorithm searches for a possible destination b, now you want to start the algorithm anew with the starting point b until you hit a deadend, from there on you go one step back to see if you can get anywhere else and so on.

In every iteration I save the way I went so in the end I have a full network of places I can go to.

**The problem is I do not know how to deal with recursions like this in node.js.**

**EDIT :**
I fixed the initializing problem and some other problems. The programm runs without errors now but there is one issue i still do not understand:
The "nodecounter" variable seems to be reseted on every iteration of the for-loop in the "separation" function. If you run the program now, you will see how the first 4 rows of my sectornodes array are filled then after hitting a deadend (jumping back to the first for-loop) it is overwritten instead of adding new rows. The "testarray" on the other hand does not loose the changes "recursion" has done in it. 
Does someone see the problem?

```
//testarray [startpoint, endpoint, marker] the marker defines if i have already visited a node (1) or not (0)
var testarray = [
    [2323, 2324, 0],
    [2326, 2322, 0],
    [2324, 2328, 0],
    [2322, 2321, 0],
    [2321, 2322, 0],
    [2328, 2324, 0],
    [2324, 2323, 0],
    [2329, 2326, 0]
];

var separation = function(testarray){       //main function to start the recursion
    var sectornodes = [];      // array with the results
    var sectorcounter = 0;      // counts the different sectors which are independent from each other
    var nodecounter = 0;        //counts the nodes (in order to fill my array)

    for (var i=0; i < testarray.length; i++){
        sectornodes[i] = [];
    }
    for (var i=0; i < testarray.length; i++){   //check all start point
        if (testarray[i][2] == 0){       //if we havent visited this place before ...
        console.log(sectorcounter);
            recursion(testarray[i][0], testarray, sectornodes, nodecounter, sectorcounter); //start the recursion with this node
            sectorcounter++;            //after every iteration of the loop we enter a new sector
        }
    }
    console.log(sectornodes);
}

var recursion = function(node, testarray, sectornodes, nodecounter, sectorcounter){     
    for (var j=0; j<testarray.length; j++){     //check every start point if he matches our node...
        if (testarray[j][0] == node && testarray[j][2] == 0){   //...if he does and we havent visited it before, ...
            sectornodes[nodecounter][0] = sectorcounter;        //...we add the route to our array...
            sectornodes[nodecounter][1] = testarray[j][0];
            sectornodes[nodecounter][2] = testarray[j][1];
            console.log(sectornodes);
            nodecounter++;                                      //...and raise the line counter
            testarray[j][2] = 1;
            //console.log(testarray);   //output for debugging: the array should gain a 1 in the 3rd argument for every iteration
            recursion(testarray[j][1], testarray, sectornodes, nodecounter, sectorcounter);                         //now we start again with the end node to see where we can get from there on
        }
    }
    console.log('deadend');     //output for debugging: output whenever a path hits a deadend (no further place where you havent been before) 
}

separation(testarray);
```

Comment: "*Can someone give me the body of a code like that?*" << No. Post your attempts (and research) first.

Comment: There you go, my code so far. Whenever I search for recursion, the used data in the examples isnt dependant so it is not comparable to my problem. But i am still looking.

Answer (score 0):

You are receiving undefined array errors because of calls like

```
sectornodes[nodecounter][0] = 'new';
```

You need to make sure you initialize the subarrays before populating them

```
if(!sectornodes[nodecounter]){
  sectornodes[nodecounter] = [];
}
```

Comment: Hello Comart and thank you for the help. I changed my code, initializing the whole array with a for loop at the beginning. I will update my code in the next minutes.